# Difference between pandas.corr and scipy.spearmanr

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

I am looking to efficiently calculate the [Spearman correlation](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/spearmans-rank-order-correlation-statistical-guide.php#:%7E:text=The%20Spearman%27s%20rank%2Dorder%20correlation%20is%20the%20nonparametric%20version%20of,association%20between%20two%20ranked%20variables.) for a large (`873901122, 273`) dataset.

Both [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) and [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html) offer implementations of this. However, their implementations produce different results.

Minimal example below:

```
from numpy.lib.npyio import load
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, scipy.stats as st

x = load_iris(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
X = x[0]

scipy_spearman = st.spearmanr(X)[0]
pandas_spearman = np.asarray(X.corr(method='spearman'))
diff = np.subtract(scipy_spearman, pandas_spearman)

print(np.array_equal(scipy_spearman, pandas_spearman))
print(diff)
```

Produces:

```
False
[[ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -1.11022302e-16  0.00000000e+00  5.55111512e-17]
 [ 1.11022302e-16  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -1.11022302e-16]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  5.55111512e-17 -1.11022302e-16 -1.11022302e-16]]
```

If they are both calculating the Spearman correlation with no randomness on the same data, why are the results different?

Comment: Lesson learn, due to floating point precision, never use `==` on floats, use `np.isclose` or `np.allclose`